# Time complexity of a Divide and Conquer

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I have Master theorem for finding complexities but the problem is Master theorem says

For a recurrence of form
$T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)$ where $a \geq 1$ and $b > 1$,
there are following three cases:

- if $f(n) = Θ(n^c)$ where $c < \log_ba$, then $T(n) = Θ(n\log_ba)$;
- if $f(n) = Θ(n^c)$ where $c = \log_ba$, then $T(n) = Θ(nc\log n)$;
- if $f(n) = Θ(n^c)$ where $c > \log_ba$, then $T(n) = Θ(f(n))$.

I have$T(n) = T(n/2) + n^2$.

My solution is that $c = 2$ and $\log_ba = \log_1 2=\infty$. So in which case does it fall and what is the complexity?

Comment: In your last sentence, you should have $\log_ba=\log_21=0$.

Comment: oh , sorry  i made a bigE

Comment: and Thanks for pointing that out - Rick @RickDecker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rick Decker points out in his comment, your error is that you have $a=1$, $b=2$, so $\log_ba = \log_21=0$.  (Not, as you say, $\log_ba=\log_12$.)